# 'message.DeliveryCount' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`. I am doing very simple thing in order to initialize `BrokeredMessage` which belongs to `Microsoft.ServiceBus`. I am running simple line which is

```
BrokeredMessage messagee = new BrokeredMessage();
```

Doing this is causing me following error below

[image]

Can someone please tell what is going here. It is causing me the error in the next step in which I am accessing the this Brokered message and gives the error  `threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`

This is the most basic thing. Why framework would do that?

Answer (score 0):

A message that has not being received from the broker has no meaningful value for `DeliveryCount` or `EnqueuedSequenceNumber`. Nothing’s wrong with the SDK. If you use the message object to send it, it will work.

P.S. if this is a new project, don’t use NuGet package WindowsAzure.ServiceBus. Rather use a later SDK, one of the two depending on the features you need. There are 3 SDKs at this point and you can find more details in [my post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/the-future-of-asb-dotnet-sdk).